# Python: Solve "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" for large text file?

Tags: python, file, text, dictionary

I have a program that reads from a text file that contains all original 151 Pokemon like this:

```
1 Bulbasaur 
2 Ivysaur 
3 Venusaur
```

My code is this

```
def dict():
    file = open("Pokemons.txt", 'r')
    d = {}
    for i in file:
        (k,v) = i.strip().split()
        d[int(k)] = v.strip()
    return d

d = dict()
for x in range(1,5):
    print (d[x])
```

And I get this as an error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
Anyway to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: Try print out `i.strip().split()` and see what you get.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `Mr. Mime` on your list?

Comment: The two species of Nidoran are likely to cause some Unicode headaches, too, even if your file doesn't put a space in their names.

Answer (score 1):

Your code proposed above works with your given txt file. However, you might have some odd data further down. I suggest you check that out and fix it, or if you need it there, use the following code:

```
def dict():
    file = open("Pokemon.txt", 'r')
    d = {}
    for i in file:
        if len(i.strip().split()) == 2:
            (k,v) = i.strip().split()
            d[int(k)] = v.strip()
    return d

d = dict()
for x in range(1,5):
    print (d[x])
```

This code **only** assigns `(k, v)` if there are two variables to assign it to. Otherwise, it is left blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Pokemon with a two word name like, "Mr. Mime", then your code will break. You need to handle it appropriately. Make the following change to your for loop:

```
for i in file:
    columns = i.strip().split()
    d[int(columns[0])] = ' '.join(columns[1:])
```